# $h$-principle for Legendrian immersions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, contact-topology, h-principle

It is "folklore" that continuous curves in contact 3 manifolds can be approximated by Legendrian curves and it seems that this follows from Gromov's $h$-principle for Legendrian immersions (in arbitrary dimensions). Since reading Gromov is a challenge (at least for me) I wonder if anybody has readable reference for this statement (preferably in any dimension) or at least for the case of approximating curves in 3 manifolds.

Comment: For the case of curves in $(\mathbb{R}^3,\xi_{\operatorname{std}})$, I believe there is a proof in *Introduction to Contact Topology* by Geiges.  Then, using Darboux's theorem, it follows that we can get piecewise-smooth Legendrian approximations along (compact pieces of) curves in arbitrary contact 3-manifolds.  But in higher-dimensional contact manifolds, Legendrians aren't curves.  Are you looking to approximate arbitrary submanifolds with Legendrian ones or looking to approximate arbitrary curves with ones that remain tangent to the contact structure?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, Kyle. The proof in Geiges is rather a "sketch" of proof and I'm a bit sceptic about the "gluing" part of his proof, but I guess this does the job for the $3$-dimensional case. As for the higher dimensional case, I didn't think about curves although I think your suggestion is interesting as well. Initially I wondered if immersed submanifolds of dimension $n$ can be uniformly approximated by Legendrian submanifolds in a contact manifold of dimension $2n+1$. But as I said, if you have a comment regarding the approximation of curves, I'm interested as well.

Comment: I only glanced through it, but this paper claims to have a rigorous, elementary argument for curves in contact 3-manifolds: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.07661.pdf

Comment: And for orientable surfaces in contact 5-manifolds, maybe this is sufficient: http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:729902/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: Many thanks. I will take a look there.